# IPA transcription of the American English "bunched" /r/

Tags: phonetics, ipa, transcription, american-english, notation

There are 2 common articulations of /r/ and /r̩/ in American English, one retroflex, and the other dorsal. This phone is called the *molar* or *bunched* r. It can be described roughly as a back-palatal or pre-velar approximant that's somewhat bunched up along the left-right axis, and it's often labiodentalized when syllable-initial. [RainDoctor cites](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/how-is-the-pronunciation-of-r-before-th-specific-case-north#comment156658_79367) John Laver as describing it as a "voiced labial pre-velar approximant with tongue-tip retraction".

I've been transcribing it ad-hoc as ⟨ɰᶹ˞⟩ or ⟨ɨᶹ˞⟩, using ⟨˞⟩ as an attempt to indicate the bunching that imparts the characteristic sound.

But this seems like an abuse of notation, and it doesn't specify *what* the articulatory change is that makes it rhotic; is there a standard way to represent this phone?

(Asking on Linguistics since it's not about the sound per se, but about the notation for transcribing it.)

Comment: I'm curious: why wouldn't you think asking about the sound *per se* is in scope here? Phonology is part of linguistics, too.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Incidentally, why did you change the angle brackets to square brackets? I thought angle brackets made the most sense since I was talking about the symbols themselves.

Comment: Ah -- turns out that the angle bracket issue was a weird Chrome issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This "**bunched or molar R**" sound is widely acknowledged as existing, but has engendered a [lot of discussion](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/bunchedmolar-r.html), not just about its symbol but its exact articulatory nature and even its acoustic distinguishability from a retroflex r.

As you note, this sound is discussed at some length in the original Laver 1994 book *[Principles of Phonetics](http://books.google.com/books?id=zxKCbu536Z8C&lpg=PP3&ots=S7yHT7j2rM&dq=laver%201994&pg=PA300#v=onepage&q=molar&f=false)*. Laver himself did not think a satisfactory symbol existed and proposed the symbol **ψ** ([Trask 1996](http://books.google.com/books?id=meRZfK_JjykC&lpg=PT217&ots=wEWNpZTHvr&dq=voiced%20labial%20pre-velar%20approximant%20with%20tongue-tip%20retraction&pg=PT217#v=onepage&q=voiced%20labial%20pre-velar%20approximant%20with%20tongue-tip%20retraction&f=false) gives this as **Ψ**). Laver also suggested potentially using the tongue-root-retraction symbol  ̙  (Unicode Combining Right Tack Below) but in a superscript position -- for which there is no Unicode symbol -- in combination with "an existing approximant symbols of suitable lingual and labial attributes". Tellingly, in my opinion, he didn't give an example of what that proposal would look like.

[Martin Ball](http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/~mjb0372/index0.html) in a [2011 poster](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:7rmPrZsi3qMJ%3aclinicallinguistics.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/poster_2_york.docx%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjQX3Bdys20OcO9RnrEkA1SbS-BTm9lssbRAXp-gy_R28iWV0DKz-QnLgRlP62_aVkrzi_UnEEI7Qn1e0Pqk-wY5P7M-zraO6_amoge3C5iiBubRHEIV14yl1aBbzBry6gidUqj&sig=AHIEtbTVLZQ4ZjOrOqgu_8Hnql6x46Aepg) [[*link to original Word document*]](http://clinicallinguistics.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/poster_2_york.docx) has proposed **ɹ̈** (alveolar approximant with the centralization diacritic) which seems reasonable, and has the advantages of being expressible in Unicode and not requiring a non-IPA symbol.

Comment: Original file: http://clinicallinguistics.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/poster_2_york.docx